# How to provide a custom column width calculation for CListCtrl?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I'm using a CListCtrl with my own "DrawItem" to draw some custom graphics into the first column, in front of the text. The text is moved ~20 pixels to the right for this. That part works.

If the user double-clicks the column divider in the header, Windows calculates the best column width. But of course Windows doesn't know my custom drawing. So the result is ~20 pixels too small for the first column.

How can I correct that?

Comment: Have you tried trapping the message for the dbl click on the column header?  You should be able to restrict the size of the column to what you need.

Comment: Not yet. I was hoping for something like "override OnCalculateColumnWidth an add 20" instead of doing it all by myself. But so far I failed to find such an overridable.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:

I can trick MFC into thinking that the list control uses checkboxes:

```
pMyList->SetExtendedStyle(pMyList->GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES);
```

The user will never ever see the system's checkboxes (because of my custom drawing), but this gives me just the space that I need.